# I want to run two 24/7 livestreams at once, both these streams will be on Youtube, is it possible?

Tags: streaming, youtube, live

I want to run two 24/7 livestreams at once (both on Youtube), using an intel nuc device with the assistance of obs studio software, is this possible?

If not, how can I run 2 24/7 streams at once without needing two computers?

Comment: I'm not sure YouTube allows 24/7 streaming. Look at Twitch.

Comment: Check out Periscope

Comment: I think you've misunderstood, I need to run 2 different streams 24/7 with pre-recorded material. But I want to do this without needing two computers.

Comment: Are the streams the same content?

Answer (score 0):

I think that will depend on the platform. I don't think YouTube allows that, unless you use two accounts. Either way, the answer is to open two instances of the upstream program (or browser for web based). Your only technical limits are your up speed and processing. Naturally, some platforms specifically block it. If we're working with recorded material, not actual live streams, then any consumer grade laptop should work.